# Horizontal ListView scrolling does not work

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a lot of columns in my database, that I want to show in a listview, so I have to make it scrollable. I tried to use properties

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
```

but it still does not work. I can see scrollbars, but I cannot scroll. Below is whole XAML listview code.

```
        <ListView Grid.Column="0"
                  Height="auto" Width="auto" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20, 20" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Libraries, Mode=OneWay}"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="30" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Telephone number" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TelephoneNumber}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Website" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding WebsiteAddress}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmailAddress}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="NIP" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NipNumber}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="REGON" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RegonNumber}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="DUNS" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DunsNumber}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateOfCommencementOfActivities}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Voivodeship" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Voivodeship}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="City" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding City}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ZIP Code" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ZipCode}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: I can see scrollbars, but I cannot scroll. Parent element is a grid, ListView's width is 800.

Comment: Is the `ListView` populated with any data?

Comment: Ah, as soon as there are items, the scrolling works. You should however remove `Height="auto" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"`

Comment: Not yet, but the horizontal scrollviewer as well does not work. It should work, because there is no enough space to show all of columns.

Comment: @Giusek Only if there is data, that should have become clear now. Otherwise put the ListView in another ScrollViewer with only horizontal scrolling enabled.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you very much! Please write it into answer to my question, then I am going to mark your idea as solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `ListView` directly inside a window, or in a `Grid` directly inside a window, the scrollbars should work as expected assuming the `ListView` is actually populated with any data.

So the scrolling only works as soon as there are items in the `ListView`. You cannot scroll an empty `ListView`. This applies to the horizontal scrollbar as well as the vertical one.

Comment: You are talking about the vertical scrollviewer, but the horizontal scrollviewer should work, because there is no enough space to show all of columns.

Comment: No. The horizontal scrollbar only works when there is data as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks for this important information. Could you tell me how could I solve my problem and make it horizontal scrollable without data? I want to be able to see all of columns.

Comment: @Giusek You already have that information in a comment on your question.